# Exchange - OnPremises - Send-on-behalf for public folders behave as Send-As

Tags: exchange, public-folders, anonymous, anonymized

We have a weird problem that has started occuring.

Mail-enabled public folders configured as Send-on-behalf-of has started behaving as if they are configured with Send-AS for users.

We have certain restrictions inhouse to NOT camouflage our users, and it is therefore against our policy to anonymize users for all public folders.

For some reason, Send-on-behalf-of rights are behaving as if there was only SEND AS configured, and all users sending mail become anonymous, which is not desirable.

I am unable to find any setting or attribute online that could have caused this.

The servers are on-premise Exhchange 2019 servers.

Anyone know what could cause this behaviour?

No users are added to the SEND AS lists, only SEND-ON-BEHALF-OF-LIST in Exchange

Answer (score 0):

Did this behavior happen recently (it was normal before), and has anything been changed? Have you checked for any errors or warnings?

Comment: it happened over a weekend, apparently without any patches and configs being applied or changed.

Comment: This is weird, feel free to post any progress.